# I am having trouble in reading date and time from an excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

```
import xlwt
import xlrd, xlutils

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
outsheet = wb.add_sheet('Page 1')

files = [r'c:\file1', r'C:c:\file2',]

outrow = 0


for f in files:

insheet = xlrd.open_workbook(f,formatting_info=True).sheets()[0]
for row in range(insheet.nrows):
    for col in range(insheet.ncols):
        outsheet.write(outrow, col,insheet.cell_value(row, col))
    outrow += 1
wb.save(r'C:\combined.xls')
```

i get output as
42753.61492
42753.61492
42753.61492
42753.61492
42753.61492

where i was looking something as this
                        2017-01-18 14:45:29 a
2017-01-18 14:45:29 a
2017-01-18 14:45:29 a
2017-01-18 14:45:29 a
2017-01-20 09:10:06 a

Comment: have you looked at `datetime` library?

Comment: yes that's not helping me

Comment: Yet, you didn't include your code using `datetime` here.

Comment: can some one say where to include datetime in my code. sorry i'm beginner

Comment: Maybe you would like using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)? You could do something like `pandas.read_excel(file, index_col=date_col_number, parse_dates=True)`

Comment: ok now i understood how to get with datetime but still my output is (2016, 12, 13, 12, 3, 41) where as i need something like 2017-01-18 14:45:29 a

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the number format when you're writing the output workbook, the same as you would in Excel. This is done by including another parameter on your `outsheet.write()` call.

Unfortunately the "official" documentation for xlwt is pretty difficult to use. Much better is the [old tutorial PDF](https://github.com/python-excel/tutorial/blob/master/python-excel.pdf). There you should read up on styles (XFStyle and easyxf).

Or even better still is to ditch xlwt altogether and switch to [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter), which is easier to use, has more features, has [vastly better documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/), is actively maintained, and generates current .xlsx files instead of outdated .xls files.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(1899,12,30) + datetime.timedelta(days=42753.61492)
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 14, 45, 29, 88000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give try to this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import xlwt
import xlrd, xlutils

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
outsheet = wb.add_sheet('Page 1')

files = [r'c:\file1', r'C:c:\file2',]

outrow = 0


for f in files:

insheet = xlrd.open_workbook(f,formatting_info=True).sheets()[0]
for row in range(insheet.nrows):
    for col in range(insheet.ncols):
        outsheet.write(outrow, col,datetime.fromtimestamp(float(insheet.cell_value(row, col))))
    outrow += 1
wb.save(r'C:\combined.xls')
```

Comment: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) got this error